# Visual Studio запускает код с ошибками

Tags: visual-studio

Когда я установил VS13 и впервые откомпилировал код с ошибками, появилось окошко, в котором мне предложили игнорировать ошибки и запускать последню удачную конфигурацию.

Подскажите, как это отключить? Чтобы проект не компилировался, если есть ошибки.
Если есть такая тема, перенаправьте, пожалуйста, не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код не скомпилировался. Студия предложила вам запустить результат предыдущей - успешной - компиляции, а не просто "проигнорировать ошибки и запустить что получилось".

Это можно отключить в  меню `Tools`/`Options` секция `Project and Solutions`/`Build and Run`. Опция называется `On run, when build or deployment errors occur...` - поменяйте `Prompt` на `Do not launch`.

В русской студии - страница `Проекты и решения`/`Построение и запуск`, опция `При выполнении, когда возникают ошибки построения или развертывания` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cyhcc7zc(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!